# NHibernate: cannot resolve inherited id property

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I have the entity defined below:

```
public class Foo : Entity<Foo.FooId>
{
    public class FooId
    {
        public virtual String Bar { get; protected internal set; }
        public virtual Int32 Buzz { get; protected internal set; }
    }

    // ...
}
```

And here's the base class:

```
public abstract class Entity<T> : IEquatable<Entity<T>>
{
    public virtual T Id { get; protected internal set; }

    // ...
}
```

I'm going to map the "Id" property as a "composite key", so I've added the following mapping class:

```
public class FooMap : ClassMapping<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        ComponentAsId(x => x.Id, m =>
        {
            m.Property(p => p.Bar);
            m.Property(p => p.Buzz);
        });
    }
}
```

And that's all pretty nice, but I get an error with the following querying attempt:

```
session.QueryOver<Foo>()
       .Where(m => m.Id.Bar == "a" &&
                   m.Id.Buzz == 2).List();
```

The error I get is:
*NHibernate.QueryException : could not resolve property: Id of: Foo*

It's quite strange, because by removing the base class and encapsulating everything within "Foo", it works like a charm.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try making the id setter public instead of protected internal?

Comment: @Stefan
Yep, and it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: I just came across the same problem. Any luck solving it?

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug and reported as [NH-3105](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3105).  It is now fixed in the most recent of the [source code](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core) and will be released as 3.3.3.GA.