# NHibernate could not resolve property of an inherited property

Tags: oop, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Why can't NHibernate access a property inherited from an abstract base class. When I try to use the property in a `QueryOver` in the `Where` clause I'm getting

> could not resolve property: ID of: TheWorkshop.Web.Models.Customer

```
var customer = Session.QueryOver<Customer>()
                      .Where(c=>c.ID ==id)
                      .SingleOrDefault<Customer>();
```

Intelisense helped me build the query and the solution compiles, so there **is** an `ID` property on the `Customer` class. The `ID` property on Customer is inherited from an abstract `Contact` class that in turn inherits from a `DomainEntity<T>` which exposes a protected field.

```
public abstract class DomainEntity<T>
{
    protected Guid _persistenceId;
    //... 
}

public abstract class Contact : DomainEntity<Contact>
{
    public virtual Guid ID
    {
        get { return _persistenceId; }
    }

    public virtual Address Address
    {
        get { return _address; }
        set { _address = value; }
    }

    //... 
}
```

and in the mapping file

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" 
                   assembly="TheWorkshop.Web" 
                   namespace="TheWorkshop.Web.Models" 
                   default-access="field.camelcase-underscore" 
                   default-lazy="true">
    <class name="Contact" table="Contacts" abstract="true">
        <id name="_persistenceId" column="ID" type="Guid" access="field" 
            unsaved-value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
        <generator class="guid.comb" />
        </id>
        <!-- ... -->
        <union-subclass name="Customer" table="Customers">
```

Following the [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14777221/96505) I updated to `NHibernate 3.3.3-CR1` from `NHibernate 3.3.2.4000` but I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that NHibernate couldn't infer from my mapping how to resolve the ID property. So although the classes compiled fine and the `_persistenceId` property on the abstract base class could be accessed through a `getter` on the implementing classes, because of the mismatch in names between `_persistenceId` and `ID` NHibernate wasn't able to follow that.

The (easier) solution was to change my names to match up. There is a harder solution which involves implementing the [IProperyAccessor](http://elliottjorgensen.com/nhibernate-api-ref/NHibernate.Property/IPropertyAccessor.html), [IGetter](http://elliottjorgensen.com/nhibernate-api-ref/NHibernate.Property/IGetter.html) and [ISetter](http://elliottjorgensen.com/nhibernate-api-ref/NHibernate.Property/ISetter.html) interfaces and in order to provide a path to pass the string `ID` in order to use the `ClassName` [access strategy](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-property).

The simpler of the two solutions was just to rename `_persistenceId` to `_id` (and update all the references to it) so

```
<id name="_persistenceId" column="ID" type="Guid" access="field" 
    unsaved-value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
```

becomes

```
<id name="Id" column="Id" type="Guid" 
    unsaved-value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
```

**Note** I was also able to drop the `access="field"` in the updated id mappings